# In Magento, if state is not there in address while registered or guest customer filling address detail,I don't allow them to place order.

Tags: magento

How to check that either state is filled by customer before checkout or not, or How to check that either state is there in already existing customer address or not? if address state is not there customer don't allow to checkout.

In short if state is not there in address while registered or guest customer filling address detail,I don't allow them to place order.

Please let me know if anyone have much idea in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add class called "required-entry" to the state textbox in magento like

```
<input type="text" id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="" title="State/Province" class="input-text required-entry">
```

in billing.phtml and shipping.phtml

Comment: But what about already register user! when they logged in shipping and billing address already set by default while checkout process, but now suppose in that address if state is not there then? that customer don't allow to checkout, in short if state is not there in address while registered or guest customer filling address detail. I don't allow them to checkout. I hope now you get my point. @pradeep Sanku

Comment: yes i got your problem.please try this code it will work.just try and see

Comment: I have tried it, but it's only working when select new address from shipping and billing drop down but what about already customer address without state?